# "Adblock interferes with login, please disable it", seems to be a bug

Tags: bug

I ain't have no adblock installed on my google chrome browser, but I keep getting this error every now and then:

[image]

*Chromium Version: 30.0.1599.114 Built on Ubuntu 13.04, running on LinuxMint 15*

Comment: Do you have any add-ons or extensions at all?

Comment: @random Nothing at all.

Comment: Can you access https://openid.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @Oded Yes I can.

Comment: This will go away completely soon, Jeremy and Oded and working hard on replacing the need for it now that we can serve that form over HTTPS everywhere.

Comment: @NickCraver Thank you very much for the hard work.